# Link to Google Map with Places name and Coordinates selects wrong location

Tags: google-maps

I'm sorry I can't list specifics here. Term of the contract and all.

The client wants links to their (very large number) of stores on google maps from their web page listings. This works for the most part, but a few it doesn't.

On the ones that aren't working, if I construct the link as `.../maps/place/My+Business/@37.4673,-78.8296,15z` it shows the correct area on the map, but the places listing shown is for another store hundreds of miles away.

If I construct the link as `.../maps/place/The+Street+Address/@37.4673,-78.8296,15z` it shows the correct area on the map and one blank marker, but not the places listing.

Searching, I was able to find the location desired, select the listing, and grab the share link. The values out of the database are not precisely the same, but within 1/100th of a degree, or about 1/2 a mile off.

Is there a way to use both the street address and location name together to get the correct very-nearly-correct-coordinates places listing to be selected? Seems strange it would select a store so far away if the coordinates are not spot on.